# nodejs 6 which asymmetric crypto for encrypted config files

Tags: node.js, encryption

I'm building an electron app and want to secure the stored user settings

my idea is that the user chooses a password on first startup and that all his config values are stored encrypted on the disk

if he starts the app he has to enter the password, i decrypt the data and can forget the password. changes to the config will then be encrypted by a corresponding public key

is there a solution to build that with the native nodejs crypto module?

if yes, which is the right algorithm for this?

i thought it would be a "simple" rsa implementation but looking at the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) i cant find any key generation method which takes a password as input?

Comment: No, it's not possible with only the crypto module and it's a lot of work to do this anyhow. You'd need to use a seedable pseudo-random number generator in order to find always the same prime numbers for the same seed (password). You usually cannot change the PRNG that is used during prime number search (for a good reason).

Comment: i had a system in mind like pgp where i store the private key next to the config file and just unlock the key by userpassword.. not to generate the key each time the user enters his password..

Comment: Sure, you can do that, but the crypto module doesn't provide the feature of generating an RSA key pair. It can only use previously generated keys.